# Ajax call on controller and get collection in grid

Tags: magento2, ajax, product-collection, product-grid, magento2.2.7

I am creating a functionality on my custom phtml.

I want simple ajax call on my controller and get product grid in response.

to ajax call I used this:

```
require(['jquery'], function($){ 
    $.ajax({
        url: "/mymodule", 
        success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

How can i get product collection and assign it to `Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml` file and in return send products collection in grid.

Comment: first check your ajax calling controller by putting echo in controller.

Comment: Yes I checked, I am getting response from controller, need product grid in response